# Git Repo was created missing many project files

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

Have a strange issue. I cloned a bluemix app I had been working on, removed the .git info, modified the manifest, package and project files and then used 'cf push' to create a new app.

It appeared to work, the new project was created in bluemix and my files were there when I looked in the Files and Logs tab, so I then clicked 'Add Git' so I could use the 'Edit Code' button. When the pane appeared all of the code files were missing from the git repo (including app.js, the views folder, etc ).

What is the easiest way to sync the files I see in Files and Logs to the repo that the project is attached to through bluemix?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens as the "Add Git" button will only clone in the files from the Boilerplate you created your app from.  In your case it looks like a Node.js app.

We are incredibly sorry for this.  Our dev team is looking making the "Add Git" button work for all projects.

Two work arounds for this are as follows.

1. Create a new app, then immediately click "Add Git", this will insure a baseline that all new files will be in your git project.
2. This one isn't as pretty but it will work.  Checkout your git project for your app that you already have created.  Add the files back to the git project and commit them.