# Bluemix edit code is out of sync with git repo

Tags: ibm-cloud

Using the Bluemix dashboard, the file list in the 'edit code' screen is a different list than my git repo. The 'edit code' file list is the starter project. I pushed a new set of source code from my local, and it's listed correctly in the Bluemix git repo. However, when I open the 'edit code' window, the file list is still the starter project. How do I update the 'edit code' window to show the updated file list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Repo was created missing many project files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225401/git-repo-was-created-missing-many-project-files)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the "Add Git" button will only clone in the files from the Boilerplate you created your app from. This is why you are not seeing the code updates you have made to your app in the created git project.

This question has previously been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225401/git-repo-was-created-missing-many-project-files). Please refer to that answer for workarounds until this functionality is remedied for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read chapter 4.3.1 of this [Microservices Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248275.html?Open)
There are several options for how to control your source code and deploy to Bluemix.  It describes how to use CLI, BluemixDevOps Services, Git and GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The EDIT CODE (Web IDE) workspace is not the same as your project's git repo.  Instead, you should think of it like a local sandbox.  When you first open the project, it performs a git clone to populate the project's files.  From here on, if you want to update the workspace with the latest files from the project's master repo, you must do so from the Git Repository 
[image: git icon] on the left, just like you would if you had cloned the project locally.

https://hub.jazz.net/docs/reference/git/